# how to reducible this SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, `class_students` and `school_students`. I need to count the total number of schools and the proportion of the whole class, but I used two identical queries. This is my query:

```
SELECT t.class_name,
       (SELECT COUNT (1) FROM school_students) as total_school_population,
       COUNT (1) / (SELECT COUNT (1) FROM school_students)
FROM class_students t;
```

so, how do I optimize it?

Comment: What does the explain/execution plan say?

Comment: I edit your question , is this is how your wuery should be ? count(1)/ count(1) on the same table ? huh

Comment: Use CTE (common table expression)

Comment: @Moudiz First `COUNT` is on `class_students`, Second `COUNT` is on `school_students` pretty confusing imo.

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct.  Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is also unclear how to calculate "I need to count the total number of schools" from the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those two table doesn't have any relationship, you can try to use to `CROSS JOIN` let subquery get result set then use the column.

```
SELECT t.class_name, 
       t1.cnt total_school_population, 
       COUNT(1)/ t1.cnt
FROM class_students t CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) cnt
    from school_students
) t1
group by t.class_name,t1.cnt
```

Comment: thank you,;)!but If there is another grade column in the two tables,and I want to count the proportion of this class in the entire grade.The query looks like this,but it is wrong,how should i do?(i don't know how to format my code in comment,so i post it at the end)【 SELECT t.class_name, t1.cnt total_school_population, COUNT(1)/ t1.cnt FROM class_students t CROSS JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(1) cnt from school_students where school_students.GRADE=t.GARDE ) t1 group by t.class_name,t1.cnt;】

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the recalculation of total school count for each record, save the value in a column user variable

```
COLUMN school_count NEW_VALUE school_count
SELECT count(*) school_count
  FROM school_students;
```

Then use this variable for the division expression

```
SELECT class_name,
       '&school_count' as total_school_population,
       COUNT (1) / &school_count as class_proportion 
  FROM class_students
 GROUP BY class_name;
```

In case the tables contain very large number of records, do gather statistics and/or use optimizer hints like 
`/*+ ALL_ROWS*/`